# How to modify a line after every 6 lines in vim

Tags: vim

I have a file with these lines:

```
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
ddd
ddd
ddd
ddd
ddd
ddd
```

i want to convert this into:

```
aaa;100;
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
aaa
bbb;100;
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
ccc;100;
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
ccc
ddd;100;
ddd
ddd
ddd
ddd
ddd
```

Is this possible in vim in one command ?

Comment: just write a simple script.....while(...){ ... count += 6; } ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yet another one

```
:g/^/ if !((line('.')-1)%6)|s/$/;100;
```

**Breakdown**

- `g/^/` Global command to apply next expression on each line
- `if !((line('.')-1)%6)` If the modulus of the current line equals 0
- `s/$/;100;` Replace the line ending with `;100;`

Comment: Thanks for the `if !((line('.')-1)%6)`, didn't know global command could do that!

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you mean by "one command", but you can do without manually repeating it for each item by using a macro:

1. Position your cursor on the first line
2. Start recording a macro named z: `qz`
3. Enter insert mode at the end of the line: `<shift-A>`
4. Enter the text you want: `;100;`
5. Exit insert mode: `<esc>`
6. Jump down six lines: `6j`
7. Stop recording the macro: `q`
8. Repeat the macro the right number more times: `3@z`

Because the jumping down 6 lines is part of the macro, it will line up properly and loop through the file.

The relevant commands here are `q#` to start recording a macro, `q` to end the recording, and `@#` to play a recording back.

More information can be found in various places, such as the vim wiki: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Macros

Answer (score 1):

If the lines are all the same until the change, this is a pretty nasty Vim solution:

```
/\v(.*)\n\zs\1@!
:%g//norm A;100;
```

Traditionally in Vim you craft a search first, then use `:%s//replace` to replace your last search with "replace". In one line it would be:

```
:%g/\v(.*)\n\zs\1@!/norm A;100;
```

I'm so sorry. This is what happens after years of Vim use. It's not pretty.

**Explanation:**

Essentially we're finding lines that AREN'T duplicated on the next line, and performing an action on them, in this case, adding some text.

- `:%g/` Perform an action on a pattern (same syntax as `%s`)
- `\v` Very magic. Makes all special characters in Vim regexes special.
- `(.*)\n` any text followed by a line break. Capture the text.
- `\zs` Start highlighting the match here. This will put the cursor on the next line after the match, where we will perform the action.
- `\1` The capture group from above `(.*)`, so a new line with the same text...
- `@!` But negate it! So the cursor will go to any line that is NOT duplicated by the previous line.
- `/norm A;100;` Peform the normal mode command `A;100;` which will execute keystrokes on each line as if you were in normal mode. Regular Vim here, just append (A) text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
:%s/\(^.*\)\(\(\n^.*\)\{5}\)/\1;100;\2
```

`^.*` match a single line

`\(...\)` group

`\{5}` repeater

Answer (score -1):

```
:%s/\v(.*)(\n.*)(\n.*)(\n.*)(\n.*)(\n.*\n)/\1;100;\2\3\4\5\6/
```